# How to forward an error from an exported function

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a React app which uses Axios for data fetching and I have written a wrapper around Axios like so.

```
import axios from "axios";

async function GET(
  url: string,
  headers: { [key: string]: string } = {},
  searchParams: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()
) {
  const response = await axios.get(url, { headers, params: searchParams });
  return response.data;
}

async function POST(url: string, headers: { [key: string]: string }, body: any) {
  const response = await axios.post(url, body, { headers });
  return response.data;
}

const API = { GET, POST };
export default API;
```

Axios throws an error when the response status code is something other than 2xx. I am trying to catch this error in a catch block and use it to show a notification to the user.

```
// a button's onClick handler
try {
   API.GET('https://www.test.com/api/users')
} catch (err: any) {
   // not able to reach here when error is thrown by axios
   console.log(err.response.data);
}
```

I am able to log the error in catch block when I use Axios directly in the try block without the wrapper code.

Why is the error not being forwarded from the `API.GET` call?

Comment: _"I am able to log the error in catch block when I use Axios directly in the try block without the wrapper code"_ - that seems improbable. Unless you mean you had `await axios...` in the handler, in which case you **still need to `await API.GET`**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for answer
adding ```await``` solved the issue, so the errors thrown by any async function calls without await in the try block won't reach the catch block. Is this kind of working the same for other languages like C# , Java ..etc.